# PostgresQL slow update

Tags: postgresql

I am moving from SQL Server to Postgres, but I faced a very primitive problem, which I solved after googling for a while, but I don't know if what I did is the official way!

I have a simple table of id integer column, tags array column and a jsonb column.

I have Gin index on the tags array field, and performance is great selecting records. I only have around 130,000 rows.

I faced a very slow update, just a very simple update append numeric value to the array column **updating the entire table 130,000 row, I am adding this part , as I think it was not clear to all**

it took around 2 minutes to complete!

When I read more about PostgreSQL, I understood that it almost rebuild my table as I update every row.

So I made 2 things I

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET (FILLFACTOR = 50);
VACUUM FULL mytable;
```

and on every query, I drop the gin index and do the update and rebuild the index.

This result in a total of 2~3 seconds instead of 2 minutes for the update.

So I think I solved my problem as dropping the index allowed HOT update, but my question is (( is it the official way to do things like this ))?

Comment: Does your UPDATE change **all** rows every time? You haven't shown the table definition, nor the index nor the actual UPDATE statement, but maybe a normalized data model (without the array) would make things more efficient. Adding an "array element" then boils down to a simple single-row INSERT statement.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the actual UPDATE statement you are doing.

Comment: As this is a migration from SQL Server: what kind of data model did you use in SQL Server as it does not have arrays? Is the GIN index on the array column or the JSONB column? Do you update the array column and the jsonb column? And why are the tags "numeric" values?

Comment: I created a quick test setup: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7ec0fc853f3915840666d8ba73905ca5 - the single row update takes 2**milli**seconds, updating 150.000 rows takes about 17 seconds.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not comparing MSSQL to postgress ,  All I am saying I am new to postgress and trying to benefit Arrays , GIN , My question is am I doing the right way or NOT.

Comment: We can't really tell what's wrong unless you provide more information. The `CREATE TABLE` statement, the `DELETE` statement and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) of the DELETE statement generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as formatted text making sure you preserve the indention of the plan. [edit] your question, paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Running `explain (analyze) update...` **will change** the rows!

Comment: @EmadOmar No, you're not doing it the right way. See a_horse_with_no_name's first comment - don't use arrays here but normalise your data model.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PostGreSQL is known to be very slow on some queries. Especially COUNT and UPDATE facing Microsoft SQL Server (and some other RDBMS).

For COUNT queries read the paper I wrote :
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/

For UPDATEs PostGreSQL is unnable to do a "in place" UPDATE and act as DELETE + INSERT....
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/is-update-the-same-as-delete-insert-in-postgresql/

Of course it is not a good pratice at all to drop an index to minimize the execution time because concurrent users wont benefits from this index and the reCREATE index will have an increasing time when you will have some more rows in your table.

Comment: It is very funny to see that some stackoverflow users abuse of minus point when an answer is done and point out the fact PostGreSQL si very slow dues to misconceptions of the PG SQL Engine !

Comment: But more importantly: there is simply not enough information in the question to actually tell *why* the UPDATE is that slow. We don't see the actual statement being used and we don't see any execution plan. To me it sounds as if Emad is updating **all** rows each time. An update to a GIN index is indeed slower than updating a Btree index, but it's quite unlikely that an update of a single row takes 2 minutes (unless the array contains millions of elements).

Comment: @SQLpro The downvotes are more likely because this answer consists basically out of links, not because postgres fanbois deny that it's slow. And it's not even clear what the article about `COUNT` performance has to do with the OP's `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course facing facts as simple as a query comming from SQL Server going to PG become slow is not a topic ?

Comment: sql serVer does not support arrays or GIN indexes, so the table structure and the UPDATE statement there must be completely different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no other RDBMS supports GIN or GIST indexes... Do you think that Oracle or SQL Server or DB2 is slower because of the lack of these type of indexes ? Or is it because GIN/GIST indexes are unefficient ??? And do you think the use of arrays in PG speed up the execution of queries ???

Comment: I never claimed that. I just pointed out that the situation is substantially different to the way the table was structured in sql serVer. So it's simply not directly comparable.

Comment: @SQLpro , so you mean there is no way than the way I did? 1.drop index 2. mass update 3.recreate index?

Comment: An index is like a speedway. Not necessary to go from Chicago to Santa Monica, but essential to go fast. If you drop an index all the other concurrent users of the database will need to drive on different small roads... So it is not a good practise to do a drop and recreate index when a database is used by many users...